# How to use variable 'object' in regex?

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
vers={jquery:"2.1.1"};
...
.pipe(replace(/src=".*\/(.*).js"/g, 'src="js/$1.min.js?ver='+vers["$1"]+'"'))
...
```

Why '...src="js/jquery.min.js?ver=undefined"...'? And how to make rightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you are actually passing in $1, not the string value. You need to use the function

```
str.replace(YourRegExp, function(fullmatch, group1) { return 'src="js/' + group1 + '.min.js?ver='+vers[group1]+'"'; });
```

Comment: thanx. `.pipe(replace(/href=".*\/(.*).css"/g, function(fullmath,group1){return 'src="css/'+group1+'.min.css?ver='+vers[group1]+'"';}))` worked rightly

Answer (score 1):

The expression `'src="js/$1.min.js?ver='+vers["$1"]+'"'` is evaluated *before* it is passed into `replace`. As such, `"$1"` has no special meaning and is treated as that literal string. This means you're trying to resolve the `"$1"` of the `vers` object and, thus, getting `undefined`.

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as its second parameter which you can use to identify the correct `vers` value at runtime and replace it as needed.